# How to add inline comments to multiline string assignments in python

Tags: python, comments

How to add comments to multiline assignments in python, as is possible in C with the syntax:

```
char sc[] = "\x31\xdb"                  /* xor %ebx, %ebx       */
            "\x31\xc9"                  /* xor %ecx, %ecx       */
            "\xb8\x46\x00\x00\x00"      /* mov $0x46, %eax      */
            "\xcd\x80"                  /* int $0x80            */
            "\x31\xdb"                  /* xor %ebx, %ebx       */
            "\xb8\x01\x00\x00\x00"      /* mov $0x1, %eax       */
            "\xcd\x80";                 /* int $0x80            */
```

but the same in python, using escaped line breaks

```
sc = "\x31\xdb" \   # xor %ebx, %ebx
     "\x31\xc9" \   # xor %ecx, %ecx
     "…"
```

Comment: I don't get what the question/problem is. The latter syntax looks as valid Python comment syntax. It's the line continuation that's wrong.

Comment: It is a real question. I understand what he is asking. He is asking for a way to put a comment in the middle of a (continued) line. As can be done with a block comment in C/C++.  **There is no such feature in python**, so the only solution (and it is a good one) is to bracket the code with parentheses, as in the accepted answer. NOTE: Triple quotes can sort-of be used as block comments in python,  but only on a separate line: if do `"""is this a comment?"""` at end of line (before backslash), it will be treated as a string in the code. In this code, would be appended to the desired string.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can write

```
sc = ("\x31\xdb"      # xor %ebx, %ebx
      "\x31\xc9"      # xor %ecx, %ecx
      "…")
```

if you want.

Comment: +1, Using brackets to get implied line continuation is the best option here.

Comment: @Lattyware Or anywhere really. Backslash line continuations are Weird And Fiddly (tm).

Comment: (And you lose editor highlighting that tells you where the line really ends.)

Comment: the reason it does not work as on the question is because the `\ ` escapes the line break. but if you put a space to add a comment, now the `\ ` escapes the space. which does nothing.  the solution here keeps the list open until the `)` is seen, which can happen on several lines. on python, the start of a comment is threated as a (unescapable) line break. in fact, the C code only works because it is expecting the `;` as well.

Comment: In fact it is a heck?